# Стилизация строки таблицы по событию

Tags: typescript, angular4, angular-material

Когда добавляется новая строка в таблицу, к конкретно этой строке должны применяться стили класса `lineStyle`. На данный момент, класс применяется ко всем строкам таблицы.

`users.component.html:`

```html
<md-table>
  <ng-container>
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Name</md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let user" [ngClass]="'lineStyle: метод(true)'">{user.name}</md-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container>
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Age</md-header-cell>
    <md-cell [ngClass]="{'lineStyle: метод(true)'}" *cdkCellDef="let user">{user.age}</md-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
  <md-row [ngClass]="{'lineStyle': isNewUser}" *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
</md-table>
```

`users.component.ts`:

```js
export class UsersComponent {
  public isNewUser: boolean;
  public constructor(public us: UsersService) {
    us.usersAddForTableEmitter.subscribe(resp => {
      this.isNewuser = resp.isNewUser;
      this.refreshUsersTable();
    })
  }
}
```

`users.service.ts`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UsersService extends BaseService<any> {

...
 private getUsersAddForTable() {
    this.getUsers(...).pipe(
      mergeMap((resp: Array<any>) => {
        const newUsers = this.transformUsers(resp);
        newUsers.forEach(user => {
          this.usersAddForTable.unshift(user);
          this.usersAddForTableEmitter.emit({
            user: user,
            isNewUser: true
          });
        });
        return this.readUsers()
      })
    ).subscribe()
  }
}
```

Comment: переменную создай типа `boolean`

Comment: @overthesanity, в users.component.ts?

Comment: ..........да :)

Comment: @overthesanity, и где его нужно использовать?

Comment: ...в шаблоне :)

Comment: ....получилось?

Comment: да, но не то, что нужно( стили применяются ко всем строкам. а мне нужно добавлять класс только к новой строке

Comment: если у тебя что-то рендерится в цикле, то в таких случаях решением может быть добавление какого-то поля к объекту массива, например `user.wasAddedRecently?: boolean` и естественно проверка в шаблоне `[class.lineStyle]="user.wasAddedRecently"`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96035/discussion-between-new-user503-and-overthesanity).